# Custom UITableViewCell setup everything in init* or use properties

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm wondering what is the best approach/design when using custom `UITableViewCell`s.

One way I'm doing it is having a init that takes all parameters necessary to setup the `UITableViewCell`. Like `-initWithLabel:groups:error`

Then I would init it like `CustomUITableViewCell *cell = [CustomUITableViewCell alloc] initWithLabel:@"Hello" groups:@[@"1", @"2", @"3"] error:NO];`

Then perhaps later if I would need to update the error of the `CustomUITableViewCell` to YES I would just reload the cell for `CustomUITableViewCell` and supply YES in the init.

Now I'm wondering if it would be "better" to have a setter for the cell, like `- (void)setError:(BOOL)error` that I can set whenever I need to update the error of the cell **instead** of reloading the whole cell.

What would be pros/cons comparing the two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first choice doesn't seems to be a good approach. If you are creating cell each time it just fine. But actually happening is table view will create only 10-15 cells(depends) and later they will be reused. So initialization is no going to perform unless you call it externally(that is not good).

So the good approach in custom cells are use the properties and expose all the things that is going to change in `cellForRow`  of your datasource object. Make your labels, error... as properties if it is accessible to the outer class. So you can easily change any values.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a member variable that can change, then for sure it should use a setter (and be a property), so you don't have to replace the class each time.  The source-code will be clearer, and the program will be more efficient. You might also include it in your init, if you think it's a good idea to encourage clients to explicitly set that variable when they make a new object.